# Accessing an object member var using iterator

Tags: c++, oop, iterator, median

I have a vector of (pointers to) objects - people. I have a function that adds income to a person. The problem I'm having is to both find a person and accessing that `addInc`. I still sometimes get confused with pointers/references and more importantly I'm new to OOP. The relevant function is:

```
bool Population::Income(const string &id, unsigned int amount) {
    Person *Candidate = new Person(id);

    //find company using lower_bound
    iterPeople = lower_bound(m_People.begin(), m_People.end(), Candidate, cmpId);
    if ( iterPeople != m_People.end() && (*iterPeople)->m_id == id ) {
        *(iterPeople)->addInc(amount);
        //request for member 'addInv' in...maybe you meant to use '->'?

        delete Candidate;
        return true;
    }

    delete Candidate;
    return false;
```

The rest of the code is [HERE](http://pastebin.com/XsgG9DkT). I have two questions:

1. How do I solve the `addInc` issue?
2. About the `lower_bound` search - that method should be fine with `NewPerson`or `CancelPerson` but `Income` is gonna get called A LOT. Is that method sufficiently quick? Any way to make it more efficient?
3. BONUS - with `addInc` also comes `MedianNetworth` which returns median of all successfully added `Income`s. The efficient way to use this is to create two heaps (min and max). My initial plan was to `make_heap` in the `Population` class:

`make_heap(m_Audits.begin(), m_Audits.end(), cmpInt);`

however I cannot make a heap inside the class because of `unexpected '(' token` - the very same syntax works in `main()` or inside any function. What am I doing wrong? Obviously I don't want to create heaps inside functions since I would have to create a new heap whenever I wanted to add an entry.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for you to use *dynamic storage* for `Candidate` in the code above. You are making life harder for yourself and others by doing that.. Why not simply use *automatic storage*?. aka simply making it a local object: `Person Candidate(id);`

Comment: Where is `iterCompId` defined?

Comment: There's no place for using `*` here, just use `iterPeople->`

Comment: Same error, `request for member 'addInc'... which is of pointer type 'Person' maybe you meant to use ->?`

Comment: You defined `vector<CCompany*>::iterator iterPeople` and you are using it to iterate over `m_People` which is a `vector<Person*>`. There's a type incompatibility here. It is unusual to define an iterator as a class member. Why not just use `auto iter = ...`, creating an iterator on the spot when needed,